# get status callback function from service

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

how to implement call-back function between component and service..Sorry I'm still new with angular and typescript.

```
getDiscount(){
    let getDisc = [];
    getDisc.push({
      price: Number(this.commonService.getPayments$.getValue())
    });
    
    this.commonService._getGlobalDiskaun(getDisc[0])
    setTimeout(() => this.getResult(),1000); 
  }
```

I'm trying to implement like above code but it give null result when network slow. How to code when `this.commonService._getGlobalDiskaun(getDisc[0])` get value then call this function `this.getResult()`

Comment: Share commonservice code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because you are using a `setTimeout` method with a 1-second delay and the result of the API might not reach in one second
You need to `subscribe` the service you are using so you can invoke the function as soon as you get the response from the API like this:

```
this.commonService._getGlobalDiskaun(getDisc[0]).subscribe(result => this.getResult())
```

you also need to `return` data in your service like this:

```
_getGlobalDiskaun(){
   return this.http.get<any>(`${your_api_address}`)
}
```

It might be a `POST` request but doesn't matter and you still need to return the response in your service

Comment: yup true.. I'm using `POST` request..It working as expected.. Thank you so much for helping